# Async Function handling different from node js v12 to v16

Tags: node.js, async-await

This is my code:

```
const pool = require('pg');

dbConfig = {};

async function getClient(dbConfig) {
    const pool = new Pool(dbConfig);
    pool.connect().then(() => console.log('connected'))
        .catch(err => console.error('connection error', err.stack));
    return pool;
}

async function getDBConnection() {
    const client = await getClient(dbConfig);
    await client.connect(function(err){
        if (err) {
          console.error('could not connect to postgres', err);
        }     
      });
    return client;
}

async function main() {
    const client = await getDBConnection();
    const query = "SELECT * FROM table limit 10";
    let response = "NO";

    await client.query(query, [])
                    .then(res => response = res.rows)
                    .catch(e => console.log(e.stack));
                console.log("DEBUG: ", client);
    console.log(response);
    return "***";
}

main().then(res => console.log(res));
```

If I run this code with nodeV12 it is waiting for main() method to complete but If I run this nodev16 it is not waiting for main() method to complete it is immediately completing with main() method promise pending in background.

This is causing my lambda functions to fail. Anyone knows whether anything major changed from nodev12 to nodev16 in the async functions are handled.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by nodev12 is waiting for main() and modev16 is not?   Does nodev16 end the program?

Comment: You are clearly using the main function as a Promise meanwhile your main function isn't really a promise I'm writing an answer to show you how to use your main function as a promise!

Comment: Async should make it return a promise and it should be usable as such, but there are several screwy things.  Not awaiting the promise in `getClient()` for instance.  That method will return before the promise is fulfilled and the connection might not be open.  That wouldn't work in any version of node tho, and I see connect is called again in the getDBConnection function.  The fact that the connect function of the 'client' or pool takes a function with an err argument seems to indicate it doesn't return a promise, but I don't know the library.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat I agree it is not the right way but there is something different in nodev16 it is waiting for pending promises in the background. I will increment version one by one where this is changed.

Comment: ^ it is not waiting for pending promises.

Comment: @Charan2628 I don't know what you mean, what exactly is the difference happening when you run your script?

From your comment that it is working in node16, I would hazard a guess that this is sample code and not a full script, and that your main() call is part of a larger script and you are expecting execution to halt when you call main().  That will not happen in any version of Javascript without it being called from within an async function and using `await main()`.

Comment: Thank you @JasonGoemaat & Moussa Bistami I was using pg@7.x.x version which is not compatible with node14x as mentioned here https://node-postgres.com/  the above code is working fine (except the double #connect calls) in pg@8.2.x version & above.

Comment: Ah, I've ran into version troubles before too, glad you got it working.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat the code inside main is async callback code for express get method. This express application is wrapped inside serverless-http for lambda service.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is it is something with the library you're using.  This code works fine:

```js
const wait = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))


async function main() {
  console.log('waiting...')
  await wait(2000)
  console.log('Done!')
}

main().then(() => console.log('main() finished'))
```

1. `getClient()` - creates a pool and connects, but will return before the promise completes because it isn't awaited
2. `getDBConnection()` - *also* calls connect and awaits it, but if the library takes a function with an 'err' argument, it seems very strange that it returns a promise...

Comment: This is working fine with node v16 it is waiting for this promise to resolve.

Comment: @Charan2628  - *what* is waiting?   no call to main() will wait without calling it with 'await'.   I don't think node will stop if there are pending promises, are you talking about the program or some function?  If you add a `console.log('after main call')` after the call to main, that will output before 'main() finished'.